# How can I split a list of lists based on a specific condition in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of quarters scores for basketball games like the one below:

```
qt_sc = [('30', '12'), ('22', '25'), ('11', '16'), ('13', '19'), ('18', '26'), ('19', '13'), ('14', '14'), ('20', '12'), ('18', '21'), ('9', '9'), ('22', '12'), ('14', '21'), ('6', '6'), ('12', '3'), ('20', '18'), ('19', '15'), ('23', '20'), ('27', '20'), ('22', '16'), ('18', '20'), ('24', '10'), ('26', '19'), ('12', '23'), ('21', '28'), ('21', '28'), ('25', '24'), ('18', '24'), ('15', '18'), ('20', '22'), ('23', '14')]
```

There are four quarters and up to four quarters for extra time.

My aim is to split this list into the individual matches, but the possible ties make that difficult.
The above list would be:

```
qt_sc = [[('30', '12'), ('22', '25'), ('11', '16'), ('13', '19')],
         [('18', '26'), ('19', '13'), ('14', '14'), ('20', '12')],
         [('18', '21'), ('9', '9'), ('22', '12'), ('14', '21'), ('6', '6'), ('12', '3')],
         [('20', '18'), ('19', '15'), ('23', '20'), ('27', '20')],
         [('22', '16'), ('18', '20'), ('24', '10'), ('26', '19')],
         [('12', '23'), ('21', '28'), ('21', '28'), ('25', '24')],
         [('18', '24'), ('15', '18'), ('20', '22'), ('23', '14')]]
```

My code below catches the first quarter of extra time but not the rest:

```
qt_sc2 = []
tie = ""
for i in range(0, len(qt_sc), 4):
    if tie:
        i += 1
    try:
        hp = sum(map(int, [x[0] for x in qt_sc[i:i+4]]))
        ap = sum(map(int, [x[1] for x in qt_sc[i:i+4]]))
    except:
        hp, ap = 0, 1
    if hp == ap:
        if hp != 0:
            hp, ap = 0, 0
            qt_sc2.append([y for x in qt_sc[i:i+4+1] for y in x])
            tie = "YES"
    else:
        qt_sc2.append([y for x in qt_sc[i:i+4] for y in x])
print qt_sc2
```

Comment: without some way to decipher which elements are extra time scores it is almost impossible

Comment: I'm not familiar with basketball games, how come in the match-split list you ideally want, the second match has four quarters, but one is a tie? If the rule isn't to have 4 non-tie quarters in a match (up to 8 quarters), what is it?

Comment: hold on, what's the meaning of first quarter of extra time but not the rest? I might get this question wrong

Comment: In my list if a match has only four quarters it is not a tie, if there are more, up to 8 in total, it means that in the four quarters of regular game it was a tie.

Each quarter of extra time is five minutes, if at the end one of the teams has more points it is the winner, if the teams are tied, there is one more quarter.

Comment: how on earth did you acquire this data not split by match in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
qt_sc = [('30', '12'), ('22', '25'), ('11', '16'), ('13', '19'), ('18', '26'), ('19', '13'), ('14', '14'), ('20', '12'), ('18', '21'), ('9', '9'), ('22', '12'), ('14', '21'), ('6', '6'), ('12', '3'), ('20', '18'), ('19', '15'), ('23', '20'), ('27', '20'), ('22', '16'), ('18', '20'), ('24', '10'), ('26', '19'), ('12', '23'), ('21', '28'), ('21', '28'), ('25', '24'), ('18', '24'), ('15', '18'), ('20', '22'), ('23', '14')]
qt_sc = zip(map(int, [x[0] for x in qt_sc]), map(int, [x[1] for x in qt_sc]))

def check_for_tie(game):
    left_score = sum([x[0] for x in game])
    right_score = sum([x[1] for x in game])
    # print "Left Score: " + str(left_score) + " Right Score: " + str(right_score)
    if left_score == right_score:
        return True
    return False

counter = 0 
output = []
i = 0

while counter < len(qt_sc):
    overtime_per = 0 
    game = qt_sc[counter:counter+4]
    while check_for_tie(game):
        overtime_per += 1
        game = qt_sc[counter:counter+4+overtime_per]

    output.append(game)
    counter = counter + 4 + overtime_per

for game in output:
    print game
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works for me:

```
qt_sc = [('30', '12'), ('22', '25'), ('11', '16'), ('13', '19'), ('18', '26'), ('19', '13'), ('14', '14'), ('20', '12'), ('18', '21'), ('9', '9'), ('22', '12'), ('14', '21'), ('6', '6'), ('12', '3'), ('20', '18'), ('19', '15'), ('23', '20'), ('27', '20'), ('22', '16'), ('18', '20'), ('24', '10'), ('26', '19'), ('12', '23'), ('21', '28'), ('21', '28'), ('25', '24'), ('18', '24'), ('15', '18'), ('20', '22'), ('23', '14')]

qt_sc2 = []
first = []
second = []

for qt in qt_sc:
    hp = sum(int(f) for f in first)
    ap = sum(int(s) for s in second)
    if len(first) // 4 > 0 and hp != ap:
        qt_sc2.append(zip(first, second))
        first = []
        second = []
    first.append(qt[0])
    second.append(qt[1])


qt_sc2

[[('30', '12'), ('22', '25'), ('11', '16'), ('13', '19')],
 [('18', '26'), ('19', '13'), ('14', '14'), ('20', '12')],
 [('18', '21'), ('9', '9'), ('22', '12'), ('14', '21'), ('6', '6'), ('12', '3')],
 [('20', '18'), ('19', '15'), ('23', '20'), ('27', '20')],
 [('22', '16'), ('18', '20'), ('24', '10'), ('26', '19')],
 [('12', '23'), ('21', '28'), ('21', '28'), ('25', '24')]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
qt_sc = [('30', '12'), ('22', '25'), ('11', '16'), ('13', '19'), ('18', '26'), ('19', '13'), ('14', '14'), ('20',       '12'), ('18', '21'), ('9', '9'), ('22', '12'), ('14', '21'), ('6', '6'), ('12', '3'), ('20', '18'), ('19', '15'),       ('23', '20'), ('27', '20'), ('22', '16'), ('18', '20'), ('24', '10'), ('26', '19'), ('12', '23'), ('21', '28'), ('21',  '28'), ('25', '24'), ('18', '24'), ('15', '18'), ('20', '22'), ('23', '14')]

games = []
game = []
for team1, team2 in qt_sc:
    game.append((team1, team2))
    if len(game) >= 4 and sum(int(i) - int(j) for i, j in game) != 0:
        games.append(game)
        game = []

for game in games:
    print(game)
```

Answer (score 0):

Al alternative to the solutions already provided would be to split the given list in two parts, the quarters belonging to first game and the rest of the quarters.

Do this in a loop until the list is exhausted:

```
def get_first_game(qt_sc):
    """ takes a list of quarter scores and returns the list split
        in two parts, those belonging to a single game from the start
        of the list, and the rest of the list.
    """
    n = 4
    team1_score = sum(x for x, y in qt_sc[0:4])
    team2_score = sum(y for x, y in qt_sc[0:4])
    if team2_score == team1_score:
        for x, y in qt_sc[4:]:
            n += 1
            if x != y:
                break
    return qt_sc[0:n], qt_sc[n:]

def get_games(qt_sc):
    """ applies the function get_first_game repeatedly
        to split up all the games
    """
    games = []
    while True:
        a, qt_sc = get_first_game(qt_sc)
        games.append(a)
        if qt_sc == []:
            break
    return games
```

First, convert the tuples of strings to tuples of integers. Then apply the `get_games` function :

```
import pprint
scores = [(int(x), int(y)) for x, y in qt_sc]
pprint.pprint(get_games(scores))
[[(30, 12), (22, 25), (11, 16), (13, 19)],
 [(18, 26), (19, 13), (14, 14), (20, 12)],
 [(18, 21), (9, 9), (22, 12), (14, 21), (6, 6), (12, 3)],
 [(20, 18), (19, 15), (23, 20), (27, 20)],
 [(22, 16), (18, 20), (24, 10), (26, 19)],
 [(12, 23), (21, 28), (21, 28), (25, 24)],
 [(18, 24), (15, 18), (20, 22), (23, 14)]]
```